# Is baldness inherited?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, genetics

There are many articles on how baldness is inherited (mostly from the mother's side of the family).

In the BBC Life program, the narrator linked baldness to higher levels of testosterone.

Is baldness inherited?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Baldness is heritable, it does have to do with testosterone and you inherit one of the responsible genes from you mum.

Specifically, a  particular variant of the gene that makes a protein called [Androgen Receptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen_receptor) is required for the most common form of baldness to develop. Androgen receptor binds to testosterone.

Interestingly, the AR gene lives on the X-chromosome. Because all males inherit their Y-chromosome for their Dad, they have to get their X- from Mum. So, if you're worried about going bald you should look at your mum's brothers to get an idea of what you might have inherited.

There are no doubt other genes that contribute to baldness.

Here's the paper that uncovered the link for AR (open access FTW):

- Hillmer, A. M., Hanneken, S.,
  Ritzmann, et. al  2005 [Genetic
  Variation in the Human Androgen
  Receptor Gene Is the Major
  Determinant of Common Early-Onset
  Androgenetic Alopecia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1226186/?tool=pubmed). *Am J Hum
  Genet*, 77, p.140-148.

Comment: Or you mum's dad, if she has no male siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, baldness is hereditary. In fact, it has to do with your mother. Apparently, you [inherit baldness from your mother](http://www.essortment.com/male-pattern-baldness-59917.html).

http://www.baldnessnews.com/general-information/baldness-and-heredity